# Does Qualcomm QCA9377 support packet injection?

Tags: kali-linux

Does QCA9377 support packet injection? If so, then how?

I am facing a problem in Kali Linux 2022.2. I successfully enabled monitor mode but get an error when perform packet injection test.

Answer (score 0):

The wireless wiki say `packet injection isn't supported yet`

[About Ath10k](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath10k)